# HTTP header information added in jquery file which cause failed to load jquery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very strange issue in my project.  Let me explain about that, my project is based on HTML, Extjs and JSON.  While loading the page in browser, in jquery file header information are adding dynamically.  I have no idea how its adding those information.  Because of this, application failed to load. Likewise in some JSON files also this HTTP information added dynamically which makes to fail loading JSON files also.  I'm getting error in browser console, when I click that error message, I got to see this HTTP info. [image] Previously the project was working as normal, past few days I'm facing this issue. I'm attaching a screenshot from jquery file.

[image]

Comment: I found that, while loading html page HTTP requests are leaked some where and it causes the jquery and json files failed to load.

Comment: If I copy the same project in other laptop and run, its working fine.

Comment: I'm not sure whether its a problem in my Wamp server or something else.  Please help..

Comment: Hi Sankar, it would help to see the HTML page that you're making the JS calls on. As an aside, given that it works fine on another machine, you could be running into environmental issues.

Answer (score 0):

The WebKitIndexedDB is depreciated from the recent update of modern browsers. The new recommendation is to use IndexedDB which is updated in modenizer code. 
You have downloaded the modernizer jquery file in your system which is not yet updated .

**Replace recent version of modernizer plugin code in your codebase.**

In the other System (It worked because the browser is not updated), update the browser and find the same issue persist.